# Rails 4 - Error in before_destroy not propagated after redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, callback

I have this code in a view for my Users resource. This code basically deletes a specific role for the user. Basically, my models are related like this:

```
Users 1<->N  Roles N->1 Profile
```

And ...

```
  <%= link_to role_path(profile_id: profile.id, user_id: @user.id), type: 'button', method: :delete do %>
    <%= button_tag class: "btn btn-default btn-danger btn-xs" do %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remover
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

As you can see, it just calls the destroy action in the Role's controller, which is:

```
  def destroy
    @role = Role.find_by(user_id: @user.id, profile_id: @profile.id)

    if @role.destroy
      flash[:success] = 'Perfil foi removido.'
    end

    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end
```

Well, I want my users to at least have one role associated to them so, in the Role model I created this:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :number_of_roles

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :profile

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :profile_id, presence: true

  private

  def number_of_roles
    unless Role.where(user_id: user_id).count >= 2
      errors[:base] << 'Usuário precisa ter pelo menos um perfil'
      false
    end
  end
end
```

This is working with exception of the errors[:base] line which is not popping up in my view. I have tried this without :base, with the :user_id field instead, with add_to_base (which did not work as is deprecated), and nothing works.

I am inclined to say that this is due to the redirect_to being done in the controller, however,I could not find out how to do it.

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: As you said, it's not working as you're redirecting to other action where the `@user` object is no longer has any error in it. As an alternative, you can put the error message in your flash message.

Comment: I moved all this validation to the controller. It worked... however I am not sure it is the best approach as I am doing validation on data in the controller when I believe I should be doing in the model, is that correct?

Comment: Controller should't be the one doing the validating. Controller should be use to orchestrate the validation.

Comment: Yeah, I figure ... I will have to refactor it ... thanks guys!